# exp function in Coq doesn't appear to terminate

Tags: coq

I'm new to Coq. I've been working through [Pierce's Logical Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/index.html). My interest is a bit out-of-scope of this excellent text as I want to get up-and-running with some math problems.

One of the first things I tried with reals (the `R` type) was this:

```
Compute exp 1.
```

Which sent Coq into an infinite loop. Can this be computed? Is the definition of `exp` only for proofs?

Doing:

```
Print exp.
Print proj1_sig.
Print exist_exp.
```

Yields:

```
exp = fun x : R => proj1_sig (exist_exp x)
     : R -> R

Argument scope is [R_scope]
 proj1_sig = 
    fun (A : Type) (P : A -> Prop) (e : {x : A | P x}) => let (a, _) := e in a
     : forall (A : Type) (P : A -> Prop), {x : A | P x} -> A

Arguments A, P are implicit
Argument scopes are [type_scope function_scope _]
exist_exp = 
fun x : R =>
(fun H : {l : R | infinite_sum (fun n : nat => (/ INR (fact n) * x ^ n)%R) l}
 => H)
   (Alembert_C3 (fun n : nat => (/ INR (fact n))%R) x exp_cof_no_R0
     Alembert_exp)
     : forall x : R, {l : R | exp_in x l}
```

Good grief!! How can I learn all of this?!

Comment: Perhaps look into how mathematicians [define the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers) to see why they're like this. You're not going to get something like a decimal expansion for `e` out of this; you're going to get a very long description of the properties of the number `e` as it relates to the rest of the numbers. You should still be able to prove things about `exp 1`, but computation will not help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to understand is that `compute` asks Coq to put `exp 1` into a form that is normal with respect to the rules of its lambda-calculus. So, Coq is not entering an infinite loop. It is just that the normal form of `exp 1` is so large that Coq takes a very long time to compute it (and display it).

In practice, no one is ever interested in the normal form of `exp 1`. So, what are you trying to compute? If you are only interested in computing guaranteed approximations of `exp 1`, I suggest looking at the CoRN or CoqInterval libraries.

If you just want to see the definition of `exp`, then your `Print` approach is fine. It shows that `exp` is defined as the limit of the traditional power series. It looks a bit ugly, because the definition also embeds the proof that it is convergent for any real number.